# Unable to encode user input values that is given to the loaded Naive Bayes model?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm trying to get a prediction using a dataset that having string values using Naive Bayes classifier. the data set having 14 columns and 12 columns are having string values.

I encoded the dataset using Labalencoder and onehot encoder and ready the dataset to use the Naive Bayes classifier.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\\\\CRC data set copies\\Testing1.csv')
columns = ['Age', 'Weight', 'Gender', 'Ethnic_Group', 'Religion', 'Smoking', 'Alchohol', 'Maritial_Status', 'Family_History', 'District', 'Blood_in_stools', 'Abnormal_Stomach_pain', 'Weight_Loss', 'Tiredness']
X = dataset[columns]
y = dataset['Class']

labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()  # encoding the categorical variables
# replacing the column0 categorical data with numeric values
for col in columns[2:]:
    X[col] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[col])

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
# creating new columns and representing true by 1
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()

labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)
```

then the model was created and saved.

joblib.dump(model, 'model_joblib')

```
# load the trained model using joblib
load_model = joblib.load('model_joblib')

predict = [[70,65,"M","b","s","Yes","Yes","MA","Y","kurunegala","P","P","P","P"]]
predict = pd.DataFrame(predict,columns=columns)
for col in columns[2:]:
    predict[col] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(predict[col])
predict = onehotencoder.transform(predict).toarray()
print('\nNew predicted value: ', load_model.predict(predict))
```

I want to get user inputs and predict a result using the saved model of naive Bayes. I tried encoding the user input using same encoding way but now it's not encoding correctly as same as the dataset values. because of this, the prediction is wrong.

Can someone help me to encode the user input values as the same values that the dataset has been encoded?

Answer (score 0):

In Line:

```
   for col in columns[2:]:
   predict[col] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(predict[col])
```

Try using labelencoder_X.transform(predict[col]) instead of fit_transform.

Comment: I tried it but it is giving an error like this : ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'M'

Answer (score 0):

During training and test you obviously *must* use the exact same encoding. If you use a new encoding for test, the results will be all wrong.

Now it can happen that some value was never seen during training. You need to decide what to do then. For example, you could introduce an "unknown" value for previously unseen values.